# Does independence from independent events imply joint independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Take three events $A,B,C$. Is it true that if $A\perp B$, $A\perp C$, and $B\perp C$, then $A\perp (B,C)$?

I don't see how to prove this. I stopped here:
$$
p_{A|B,C}=\frac{p_{A,B,C}}{p_{B,C}}=\frac{p_{A,B,C}}{p_{B}p_{C}}=???=p_A
$$

Comment: It is good that you fail to prove this implication since it is wrong in general (as has been explained many times on the site, for example with events of size 2 on a space of size 4 endowed with the uniform probability).